# How to move/change flutter quick action/more action order

Tags: flutter, dart

i always use `shift+ctrl+r` to do `more action` and the most action i use is `wrap with widget` but the location of the action is in the middle i have to use my mouse to select it or press down key many times to select it. is it possible to change/move the action order ? if i want to move the wrap with widget action to the top and i want to move the `Extract` section to under of more action

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just go to the widget and select :

```
alt+enter
```

and then select from your arrow keys and press enter